# Comma Code (Python) (Automate The Boring Stuff)

Tags: python

This is an exercise in the Automate The Boring Stuff book. I am supposed to create a function that takes a list value as an argument and returns a string with all the items separated by a comma and a space, with 'and' inserted before the last item. My code also includes a loop for the user to create their list.

```
def add_and(alist):
    if ((alist != []) & (len(alist) > 2)):
        for item in alist[:-1]:
            print(item + ", ",end="")
        print("and", alist[-1])
    elif ((alist != []) & (len(alist) == 2)):
        print(alist[0], "and", alist[1])
    elif ((alist != []) & (len(alist) == 1)):
        print(alist[0])
    else:    
        print("")
        
your_list = []
while True:
    print("Enter An Item or nothing")
    item = input()
    if ((item) == ""):
        print("")
        break
    else:
        your_list.append(item)
        continue

add_and(your_list)
```

I know that the code works, but I was wondering if there were any faux-pas that I am implementing, or if there is anything I could obviously do to make it cleaner. Thanks!

Comment: You've not implemented the correct solution for the question. Your task is to "_create a function that ... returns a string_".   The function you wrote prints the result but returns nothing.

Comment: If I replace my "print" with "return", would it be correct?

Comment: The last two in the function could be replaced by `return`, the middle one would need modification, but could also be replaced.  But the first two cannot be.  You can only return from a function once, not multiple time in a loop; the first `return` executed terminates the function.

Comment: You can edit the question to match what the code does, and then we can review what you have written, or we can attempt to migrate the code to _Stack Overflow_, where you might get assistance with fixing the code to do what the problem asks. Which would you prefer?

Comment: Given the original intent of the post I'm leaning toward the former.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Don't surround sub-predicates or predicates with parens when that isn't needed
- Use logical `and` rather than binary `&`
- Use `join` rather than a `for`-and-concatenate
- Factor out common sub-predicates for your list emptiness checks into an outer `if`
- Don't `else`-after-`break`
- No need to continue
- Gather your input in a separate function
- Do not leave the `input` prompt blank

Suggested:

```
def and_add(alist):
    if len(alist) > 1:
        print(', '.join(alist[:-1]), 'and', alist[-1])
    elif len(alist) == 1:
        print(alist[0])
    else:
        print('')

def get_input():
    while True:
        item = input('Enter an item or nothing: ')
        if not item:
            return
        yield item

and_add(list(get_input()))
```

Comment: Thanks! Why can't you else-after-break?

Comment: You can, it's just redundant.